# orange canva file widget import error

Tags: file, csv, import, orange

I am trying to import a semicolon CSV file in orange which has a very large number of columns (6010 mainly floats but some strings). Orange quits without any explaining message...

I then tried to import a CSV with fewer columns, it worked but separator was not recognised.

Is there a way to tell the file widget that I use ";" as separator or do I have to hack some code of my own ?
Is there some limitation on the numbers of fields or records that can be imported by the file reader widget or is my import possible?

Answer (score 1):

The File widget in Orange does not yet support specifying separators. You can currently use the 'CSV File Import' widget to do this (note that this widget will be merged into the File widget some time in the near future).